# How to create an android line graph using titanium

Tags: android, graph, titanium

Please I need to create a line graph that works for android using titanium. I have read about some javascript libraries but I just can't seem to get any one working. Any resource would do.

Comment: More info? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried dygraphs (I got it to display in my computer's browser but not on the emulator). I have also tried rapheljs but I found out that it only works for iOS.

Comment: Raphael works fine in Android now (Apr 2015). Make sure that you change the .js extension to .lib and there is a weird path issue. I found I had to provide a relative path from the html file itself to get it to load when using the <script src="raphael-min.lib"></script> approach. But it does work with some fiddling about. (Note: I am talking about using a webView to display a local html file which can leverage the raphael library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [This Link](http://dygraphs.com/) this is very useful and working for me. I am also useing in App for android. 
Try this HTML Code
~~~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['imagechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'name', 'Expenses'],
            ['April',1000,    'A'],
                ['May',  1170,   'B'],
                ['June',  660,   'C'],
                ['July', 1030,  null]
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 400, annotationColumns:[{column:2, size:15, type:'flag', priority:'high'},], title: ''});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

~~~

Comment: I have seen the link but I just cannot get it to run. How did you do yours?

Comment: Thanks, I've successfully displayed it using a web view. But one more thing. I want to know how dygraph is used within the code you gave and what the google jsapi is doing. Thanks again.